# Device to "freshen" an unventilated bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, odors

Is there a device that ozone-ises or ionises the air to reduce the odour that builds up in an unventilated bathroom?

I'm not talking about reducing smells created by - eh - "toilet deposits", more the smell that builds up because there is exposed water in an unventilated room.

**Update**
This is indeed an infrequently used bathroom, in my inlaws basement. I need to do some wiring work down there and thought if there was a device I could wire in to help I'd do so.
I thought I'd seen things in bathrooms in Pubs & Restraunts that does this, possibly not.

Comment: my favorite device for this is a flame powered wax vaporizer... aka a candle.

Comment: I'm going to guess this is in a second/third/guest bathroom, since it sounds like the water must be sitting for quite some time undisturbed.  You might want to get in the habit of occasionally flushing the toilet and running water down the drains (sink,tub,etc).  If a drain is left too long unused the water in the trap can evaporate, allowing sewer gases to escape into the room.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the commercial air fresheners are battery operated.  You can get something that looks much better and works just fine for home use (e.g. reed diffusers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a small dehumidifier in the room, which will cut down on musty smells.

Also if this bathroom is used infrequently, be sure the flush the toilet periodically, and run the faucet.  Stagnant water in the toilet will stink, and the drain trap will dry out, leading to sewer gas smells.  This will be especially true with a dehumidifier, which will dry things out.